# How to use Vuelidate with editable Vuetify Data Table field

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vuelidate

I would like to add Vuelidate validation to an editable field in a Vuetify data table. However, I do not know how to make it work with the props.item parameter.

[image: Vuetify Data Table]

For a normal input field I would do something like

```
:error-messages="qtyErrors"
@input="$v.quantity.$touch()"
@blur="$v.quantity.$touch()"
.
.
validations: {
  quantity: { required, numeric }
}
```

I do not know how to make this work for props.item.squareFootage. I am not sure how to get a handle on the index. Here is my data table. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
<v-data-table
  :headers="bldgHeaders"
  :items="selectedBldgs"
  :pagination.sync="paginationSelected"
  class="elevation-1"
>
  <template slot="items" slot-scope="props">
    <tr>
      <td>{{ props.item.buildingNumber }}</td>
      <td>{{ props.item.description }}</td>
      <td>
        <v-edit-dialog
          :return-value.sync="props.item.squareFootage"
          lazy
          large
        > {{ props.item.squareFootage }}
          <v-text-field
            slot="input"
            v-model="props.item.squareFootage"
            label="Edit"
            single-line
          ></v-text-field>
        </v-edit-dialog>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to render a dialog for each row in your datatable. Render one dialog on the page and keep track of which row the user is editing in a data property. This property is called "currentItem" in the below snippet. You can then bind your validations to the properties in just that one object instead of creating validations for every row in the table. If you don't want to use v-dialog you can also use [v-menu positioned absolutely without an external activator](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/menus#example-absolute-without-activator).

```js
const {
  required,
  maxLength,
  email
} = validators
const validationMixin = vuelidate.validationMixin

Vue.use(vuelidate.default)

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      editDialog: false,
      currentItem: {},
      headers: [{
          text: 'Dessert (100g serving)',
          align: 'left',
          sortable: false,
          value: 'name'
        },
        {
          text: 'Calories',
          value: 'calories'
        },
        {
          text: 'Fat (g)',
          value: 'fat'
        }
      ],
      desserts: [{
          id: 1,
          name: 'Frozen Yogurt',
          calories: 159,
          fat: 6.0
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: 'Ice cream sandwich',
          calories: 237,
          fat: 9.0
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  validations: {
    currentItem: {
      fat: {
        required
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    openEditDialog(item) {
      this.currentItem = Object.assign({}, item)
      this.editDialog = true
    },
    validate() {
      this.$v.currentItem.fat.$touch()
      if (!this.$v.currentItem.fat.$error) this.editDialog = false
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuelidate/dist/validators.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuelidate/dist/vuelidate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900|Material+Icons' rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="app">
    <v-app>
      <v-content>
        <v-container>
          <v-data-table :headers="headers" :items="desserts" class="elevation-1">
            <template slot="items" slot-scope="props">
              <tr @click="openEditDialog(props.item)">
                <td>{{ props.item.name }}</td>
                <td class="text-xs-center">{{ props.item.calories }}</td>
                <td class="text-xs-center">{{ props.item.fat }}</td>
              </tr>
            </template>
          </v-data-table>
        </v-container>
        <v-dialog v-model="editDialog" width="500">
          <v-card>
            <v-card-title class="headline grey lighten-2" primary-title>
              Set Fat Content
            </v-card-title>

            <v-card-text>
              <v-form>
                <v-text-field label="Fat" v-model="currentItem.fat" required :error="$v.currentItem.fat.$dirty && $v.currentItem.fat.$error">

                </v-text-field>
              </v-form>
            </v-card-text>

            <v-divider></v-divider>

            <v-card-actions>
              <v-spacer></v-spacer>
              <v-btn color="primary" flat @click="validate()">
                Save
              </v-btn>
            </v-card-actions>
          </v-card>
        </v-dialog>
      </v-content>
    </v-app>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: FYI I am just now getting a chance to work on this solution. I apologize for the delay and will update once I have implemented.

Comment: Wanted to check back around to see if you were able to implement that solution or have any questions about it?

Comment: I've implemented your solution. The only issue I am having is how do I assign the currentItem back to the props.item? Thanks.

Comment: So the lazy/wrong way to do this would be to just assign this.currentItem = item in the openEditDialog method. This will bind the same object in the list to currentItem so any changes made to currentItem will change props.item. BUT the more correct way to do this would be to remove the old element from desserts and replace it with new edited element. If your list has a proper identifier property on each item this can be done pretty easily.

Comment: very helpful for `@click="method(props.item)"`

Answer (score 0):

The vuelidate library supports Collection with the $iter keyword. You only need to declare your item's data stucture under the $iter keyword and vuelidate would build validation object for each item. For the example, you can check here https://vuelidate.js.org/#sub-collections-validation.

However, the problem happens at accessing these validation object in v-data-table's row template. Since the generated validation objects is only accessible by iterator, it is not a list, the code in row template need a way to access these validation objects. Here I worked two helper functions: getV() for accessing validation object and getVModel() validation object's data model.

```
getIter () {
  return Object.values(this.$v.items.$each.$iter)
},
getV (item) {
  if (!item.vLink) item.vLink = this.getIter().filter(i => i.$model.Id === item.Id)[0]
  return item.vLink
},
getVModel (item) {
  return this.getV(item).$model
},
```

Then in vue's template, the row template's :class can uses getV() for accessing $invalid or $dirty and the row template's v-model can uses getVModel() for accessing data.

Here is the example:

```js
v-data-table(:headers="headers" :items="items" item-key="Id")
  template(v-slot:body="{ items }")
    tbody
      tr(v-for="item in items" :key="item.Id" :class="{ vmodified: !getV(item).$invalid && getV(item).$dirty, verror: getV(item).$invalid }")
        td
          input.table-input(type='text' v-model="getVModel(item).Vendor" @input="onChangeItem(getV(item))")
        td
          input.table-input(type='text' v-model="getVModel(item).Material" @input="onChangeItem(getV(item))")
```